# Android build error after installing cloud_firestore dependency

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to connect my app to Cloud Firestore with cloud_firestore dependency but the problem occurred with android after I install this dependency. I received this error [Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0nXI.jpg)

After that I can’t build the android app to test it on the emulator but on iOS it works just fine.

I also migrated to androidx already as I found in the document I read before.
So anyone have any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Top 2 errors you will face and solutions:

ERROR 1:

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

SOLUTION

I had the same issue and combined two suggested fixes to get it to finally work:

1: minSdkVersion 21, change to 23

2: run "flutter pub upgrade"
= issues fixed!

To double-check what the fix was:
I also reverted back to 21 and invalidated + flutter clean and the issue appeared again. Then I changed to 23 and the warnings disappeared!

ERROR 2:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: io.flutter.BuildConfig
at com. android. builder. dexing. D8DexArchiveMerger. getExceptionToRethrow (D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
at com. android. builder. dexing. D8DexArchiveMerger. mergeDexArchives (D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:55)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
    ... 30 more

SOLUTION:

I received the same error, but after `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` everything works great.